# him/his - what is the right one and why?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I'm not sure what is the right answer:

> I'm looking forward to him/his visiting me next week.

Many thanks.

Comment: Neither,  it's *his visit*, or active *to welcoming him*

Comment: Both of these are correct.  It depends on whether you want "visiting me next week" to be an noun phrase or the beginning of a verb phrase.